# jQuery mobile data-transition on all links

Tags: jquery-mobile

Please help me. In jQuery mobile, how I can define a default `data-transition` attribute for "`a`" tags(e.g. "pop")? I have tried `$("a").attr("data-transition", "pop");` but it doesn't affect on the links, without `data-transition` attribute.

The default `data-transition` value is "fade".

Thank You for answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set defaults of jQuery Mobile this way.

```
<head>
 <script src='jquery.js'></script>

  $(document).on('mobileinit', function() {
   $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'pop'; // pages / popup transition
   $.mobile.defaultDialogTransition = 'pop'; // dialogs
  });

 <script src='jquery_mobile.js'></script>
</head>
```

Such settings should be loaded after jQuery and before jQuery Mobile is loaded.

Comment: @Ross navigation is based on `<a>` anchors :)

Comment: Sorry I've been having a tough time providing help lately.  Why is it that all my answers that work are criticized?

Comment: @Ross who criticized your answers? this one? sometimes the OP isn't clear, so your answer might not be correct although it works.

Comment: Sorry, you didn't criticize this answer.  Yesterday someone else criticized my answer that the OP even thanked me for and it worked to solve his question.  The reason it was criticized is because it wasn't as short/concise of code as the other answers although it did the exact same thing...  I don't understand this kind of negativity on here because it just gives a bad vibe and makes you feel reluctant to help someone because of the criticism you might get.

Comment: @Ross undelete your answer. You shouldn't have cared for what others say, as long as your answer is correct and has no mistakes. Take it easy, offer help whenever you can, ignore what negative ppl say.

Comment: @Omar in synonyms page, if possible could u vote for jqm? http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-mobile/synonyms

after this questions tagged jqm will be automatically remapped to jqyery-mobile..thanks!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33518/discussion-between-omar-and-hungerpain)

Comment: just to improve the answer, you have to wrap the JS in `<script>` tags :)