# JQuery Mobile: Disable page transitions only on back/forward buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, jquery-mobile, back-button

I am new to JQuery Mobile (1.4.5) and have just finished my first project with it.

The only problem is with page transitions on iOS7+ (in my case the slide transition). While they work fine within the site and back/forward buttons, if someone swipes the left or right edge of the iOS device to navigate browser history, there's a double transition, since the native iOS slide and JQM's slide happen in succession. This appears to be an issue with any page transition (except "none" of course). It even happens on JQuery Mobile's demo pages. I've seen others report this issue with no reliable solution.

Since there is currently no way in iOS Safari to detect history swipe events, I figured the next best thing is to turn off transitions (set to 'none') but only if back/forward events are triggered (which I assume also applies to the swipe left/right for iOS7+). I know I'll lose the transition on the back/forward buttons, but they would still work within the site so that's a compromise I'm willing to make. However I'm not sure where to go in JQM's code to achieve this.

TL;DR: Is there a way to set JQuery Mobile page transitions to 'none' only when the browser's back (and/or forward) button is pressed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this [article](https://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/12/01/detect-back-navigation/), yes you can. When browser's buttons are used, `options.direction` returns either `back` or `forward`. And then change `options.transition` to `none`.

```
$(document).on("pagecontainerbeforechange", function (e, data) {
  if (data.options.direction == "back" || data.options.direction == "forward") {
      data.options.transition = "none";
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. One gold star for you! Although now there's a new problem. When the iOS slide is finished, there's a flicker of the old page before the new one is shown. That's unrelated to the issue I posted, but it's a start! I'll see if there's a solution for that.

Comment: Just to follow up, I have confirmed the pagecontainerbeforechange event does not fire until after the native iOS slide has completed, which is causing the flicker between old and new pages. Not sure if there's any way around that. Hoping I don't have to turn off ajax completely.

Comment: @kinless try remove flicker using css `.ui-page { -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; }` and also try a different event `pagecontainerbeforetransition`.

Comment: I in fact used this to disable the transitions at all, since `$.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'none';` wasn't working for me...

Comment: @arod you probably not changing settings in `mobileinit`. I found this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17659501/4469330) which does exactly what you need.

Comment: @ciccolina thank you! the counter-intuitive part that I was doing wrong is to do that line _before_ loading JQM